# How to get a $substr of an existing field for re-insertion?

Tags: mongodb

I wish to parse out some content from one set of mongo documents into 
another. In this code:

```
sub = {number: {$substr: [stf.subject_code, 0, 5]}, description: stf.decription};
subid = db.subjects.update({number: sub.number}, sub, {upsert: true});
```

stf is a mongo document, stf.subject_code contains a string like "12345blahblahblah".

I'd like sub.number to contain the first five characters of stf.subject_code for 
subsequent re-insertion into another collection (as a string: "12345").

I've tried mongodb documentation, there's no usage example there unfortunately. Also, other similar questions/answers here are helpful, but I'm clearly still missing something.

Comment: You can use normal Javascript (if that is the language you are using, it looks like it) operations to do that.

Comment: @Thilo, thanks. Sorry, I should have said I'm working in the mongo shell, so the javascript substr() function isn't (doesn't seem to be) available to me there.

Comment: Why not? `MongoDB shell version: 2.0.1
> "xxx".substr(0,1)
x`

Comment: You, Sir, are a scholar and a gentleman! Thank-you, @Thilo! :-)